# Forward proxy to redirect HTTPS URL to internal

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy, squid

I'm trying to come up with a solution where I can do the follow:

In my scenario there are 2 servers.

API1: Nginx + API Website

API2: Nginx + Staging Website

In order to check new version of API via mobileapp, I want to set my phone to use a proxy server (Should be API2), and only when the dest URL is https://api.test.com it will redirect it internally to localhost:6000.

Any ideas of how it can be done? I know Nginx does not support SSL Proxing, but maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Eventually I was able to accomplish that by using Apache Traffic Server which has been configured as a forward proxy while doing some map rules to redirect traffic from https to localhost:443/

But, I will be happy to hear some more ideas.

Thanks